# The second query is efficient and does not require a table join

Tags: java, hibernate

From the hibernate reference:

The special property (lowercase) id can be used to reference the unique identifier of an object.
See Section 16.5, “Referring to identifier property” for more information.

```
from Cat as cat where cat.id = 123
from Cat as cat where cat.mate.id = 69
```

The second query is efficient and does not require a table join.

Why does the second query not need a table join and why did it mention it as efficient?

Comment: Please provide more context, like a link to the doc.

Comment: with that little information i would guess: cat.mate in the database is a foreign key to the mate.id. Therfor the query can probably executed as `select * from cat where mate=69`

Comment: How do you expect me to provide more information when I just copy pasted literally whatever information was available?

Comment: @Pablo, you should write that to the hibernate documentation team.

Answer (score 0):

OP question is from [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where). Why doesn't need a JOIN. Because as Hibernate says:

> Referring to identifier property
>
> References to composite identifier properties follow the same naming
> rules. If the entity has a non-identifier property named id, the
> composite identifier property can only be referenced by its defined
> named. Otherwise, the special id property can be used to reference the
> identifier property.

[Quoted From Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-identifier-property)
cat.mate.id has an identifier property that's why it doesn't need a Join and is using the Id for referencing that row. That's why the second query is more efficient than a query with a join. So in the end if you have a good mapping strategy it will be more efficient!